# Problems of parse error on input ‘xs’ [ Haskell ]

Tags: haskell

```
newtype Set a = Set { unSet :: [a] }
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord)

reduca :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> Set a
reduca [] = Set { }
reduca (x:xs) | x `myelem` xs   = Set { reduca xs }
                | otherwise       = Set { x : reduca xs }
    where myelem :: (Eq a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
          myelem x [] = False
          myelem x (y:ys)
            | x == y = True
            | otherwise = myelem x (ys)
```

I met a problem when compiling this Haskell code. A set is created in the begining and the function of 'reduca' is aiming to delete repetitive element from the lists.
The error shows

```
Prelude> :l reduca
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( reduca.hs, interpreted )

reduca.hs:26:52: error: parse error on input ‘xs’
   |
26 | reduca (x:xs) | x `myelem` xs   = Set { reduca xs }
   |                                                ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

How can I change it? Really appreaciate your help!

Comment: Use `Set (reduca xs)`

Comment: the code snippet and error output don't match

Comment: Sorry I have changed my func name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct `Set`s here by two means: as `Set (reduca xs)`, or with `Set { unSet = reduca xs }`, but not a combination of the two.

You thus can construct the `Set` with:

```
reduca :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> Set a
reduca [] = Set ( [] )
reduca (x:xs) | x `myelem` xs   = Set (reduca xs)
              | otherwise       = Set (x : reduca xs)
    where …
```

This will not work since `reduca xs` returns a `Set a`, whereas this needs to be a list (`[a]`) when using the `Set (reduca xs)` expression.

You can implement this with a helper function that will wrap the result in a set, so:

```
reduca :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> Set a
reduca ls = Set ( uniq ls )
  where uniq [] = []
        uniq (x:xs)
          | x `elem` xs = uniq xs
          | otherwise = x : uniq xs
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the exactly the solution after my attempt just now